# Check if argument of type object casts to integer or string

Tags: c#, casting

I have a method that I want to serve as dual purpose, depending on whether the argument being passed is actually an integer or string value.

How would i check if 'info' in the following is an integer or string value?

```
public void Place (object info){


}
```

I know about overloading, but for reasons I won't go into can't change the calling method. Type 'object' is always being passed. Kind of kludgy but going to test for integer and string cast values.

Comment: What about overloading the method?

Comment: Integer.TryParse: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx . Although, pedantically, a false result just proves it's not an int32, not that it is unparseable as any other kind of number. Anything can be a string. Do you mean it must be only interpretable as a string, or merely not interpretable as an int? P.S. Overloading as suggested by Plutonix is arguably a cleaner and clearer approach.

Comment: `if(info is int)`  the `is` keyword is made for this.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `object` as the parameter, a better option would be to overload the method.

```
public void Place (string info){ ... }

public void Place (int info){ ... }
```

if you can't change the method signature for some reason then you'll need to do:

```
public void Place(object info)
{
       if(info is int){
           int result = (int)info;
           ...                   
       }
       else if (info is string){
           string result = (string)info;
           ...
       }
}
```

Comment: yes, I know about overloading, but for reasons I won't go into can't change the calling method. Type 'object' is always being passed. Kind of kludgy but going to test for integer and string cast values.

Comment: @eco_bach you should have put that into question from the beginning. I did that for you... please try to put all information you have into questions in the future.

Answer (score 4):

C# 7.0 introduced pattern matching. This enables matches based on a specific class or structure. Since you can't change the signature of the method, this is the best option at the moment.

Code becomes simpler using the `is` expression to assign a variable if the test succeeds:

```
public void Place( object info )
{
    if ( info is string infoString )
    {
        // use infoString here
    }
    else if ( info is int infoInt )
    {
        // use infoInt here                
    }
}
```

If statements are limited to test the input to match a specific single type. If you want to test specific cases, the switch pattern matching becomes a better choice:

```
public void Place( object info )
{
    switch ( info )
    {
        // handle a specific case
        case string infoString when infoString.Contains( "someInfo" ):
            // do something
            break;

        case string infoString:
            // do something
            break;

        case int infoInt when infoInt > 10:
            // do something
            break;

        case int infoInt:
            // do something
            break;

        default: 
        // handle any other case
        break; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, make it a generic method like

```
public void Place<T> (T info)
{   
   // your code here
}
```

You can call it closing the type like

`Place<int>(23)` Or just `Place(23)`

Comment: Turned out OP can't change signature... Also I don't think it helps much in providing different versions of the code for `Place` method depending on type but rather just making type easier to obtain - still need `if ` of some sort to check type.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. that's strange ... signature can't be changed but the code can be. Well in that case as well you can use this as wrapper